# stepwise clustering

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

Assume that we have 3 features in our dataset and we aim to cluster them. Assume that first two variables are in the same scale and have a "similar nature" and the third one has totally different values (say, much higher values).

Would it be a valid approach here to do first clustering based on first two variables and then, inside each cluster to make clusters based on the third variable (or, vice versa, i.e. the first step is for third variable)?

Comment: You should consider normalizing all 3 variables first and then conducting clustering.  The normalization process will eliminate the larger value contribution of the third variable.

Comment: Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056974/k-means-clustering-interpretation/57061415#57061415.  My answer shows the difference with and without normalization.